# What abilities do %health damage?

Tags: league-of-legends

I like to play as Dr Mundo, stacking health. Its not uncommom for me to reach 6k health. However, there are some champions that have the ability to do damage equal to a percent of your health. I was wondering if i could have a list of these champions so i know who to watch out for. Idealy, i would also like to know what type of damage (physical, magical, true) these abilties do. Also, i do not care if the ability does max health, current health or missing health.

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't prefer a, "How do I combat % health damage?" question? Asking for a simple list of sources doesn't make for a very good question, as it's nothing more than a list.

Comment: That's not really true though, there's only two items that deal %hp damage, and the blade hardly counts if nobody uses it (referring to the hotfix from yesterday).

Comment: BotRK is still very likely to be a popular item since it is still very strong (I saw multiple blades in every game I've been in since the hotfix).  Also, if there is a 6K HP Mundo running around, surely they other team will build BotRK.  Anyway, when I play high HP champions, the main champion I worry about is Warwick since his Q is spammable and does %health magic damage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### CHAMPIONS:

---

#### Magic damage:

- **Amumu**'s Despair deals % *max* hp in a small AoE around him over time as long as the ability is toggled on
- **Brand**'s Blaze passive deals % *max* hp when he deals damage with any of his spells
- **Dr. Mundo**'s Infected Cleaver deals % *current* hp
- **Elise**'s Neurotoxin deals % *current* hp
- **Elise**'s Venomous Bite deals % *missing* hp
- **Evelynn**'s Agony's Embrace deals % *current* hp in a targetted AoE
- **Fizz**'s Seastone Trident's passive deals bonus damage % *missing* hp on basic attacks
- **Garen**'s Demcian Justice deals bonus damage based on target's *missing* hp
- **Jayce**'s Thundering Blow deals % *max* hp
- **Kog'Maw**'s Bio-Arcane Barrage deals % *max* hp on auto-attacks as long as the ability is active. Also increases his maximum auto-attack range
- **Malzahar**'s Null Zone deals % *max* hp over time in a targetted AoE
- **Mordekaiser**'s Children of the Grave deals % *max* hp over a long duration. If you die while affected by this, you become Morde's "pet" for a limited time.
- **Nasus**' Fury of the Sands deals *max* hp in an AoE around him as long as the ability is active
- **Poppy**'s Devastating Blow deals bonus damage based on target's % *max* hp
- **Varus**'s Blighted Quiver (upon activating the passive marks) deal % *max* hp
- **Veigar**'s Primordial Burst deals increased damage based on target's *missing* hp
- **Warwick**'s Hungering Strike deals % *max* hp

#### Physical damage:

- **Jarvan IV**'s Martial Cadence deals % *current* hp as bonus damage on his basic attacks
- **Kha 'Zix**'s Taste Their Fear (With Evoled Enlarged Claws) deals bonus damage based on target's % *missing* hp to Isolated targets
- **Lee Sin**'s Resonating Strike deals % *missing* hp
- **Nidalee**'s Takedown deals increased damage based on target's *missing* hp
- **Riven**'s Windslash deals increased damage based on target's *missing* hp
- **Vi**'s Denting Blows passive deals bonus damage based on target's *max* hp
- **Volibear**'s Frenzy active deals increased damage based on target's *missing* hp
- **Xin Zhao**'s Crescent Sweep deals % *current* hp in an AoE

#### True Damage:

- **Vayne**'s Silver Bolts deal % *max* hp every third basic attack against a single target

### ITEMS:

---

#### Physical damage:

- **Blade of the Ruined King**'s (Not available on the Crystal Scar) passive deals % *current* hp on basic attacks
- **Blade of the Ruined King**'s active deal % *max* hp and also heals the user for that same amount. Effect also lowers your move-speed and boosts the user's

#### Magic damage:

- **Blackfire Torch**'s (Twisted Treeline and Crystal Scar only) passive deal % *max* hp when you deal magic damage. Uses 1 charge per second and contains 18 at once, which are restored over time when not used.
- **Deathfire Grasp**'s active deals % *max* hp and increases magic damage done to that target for a limited time
- **Kitae's Bloodrazor**'s (Crystal Scar and Proving Grounds only) passive deals % *max* hp on basic attacks
- **Liandry's Torment**'s (Summoner's Rift and Proving Grounds only) passive deals % *current* hp when you deal magic damage

In addition to all of these, **Mikael's Crucible**'s active heals a single ally for a % of their *missing* hp

Comment: Missing Irelia, Ahri, and Entropy as sources of true damage.

Comment: @SadlyNot Those aren't % health though, just flat true damage. The other answer mentions them, but only because they also pose a threat to tanks.

Comment: Fair enough, keep them out then :)

Comment: is Darius' ult %health?

Comment: @Paralytic No, it does a base amount of damage that is multiplied by 20% for each stack of Hemorrhage on the target.

Comment: %missing health can't be taken cause the fact that you have 1k or 6K HP doesnt changes the damages

Comment: @Hystic 50% of 6,000 = 3,000. 50% of 1,000 = 500. If a champ does 10% missing hp it will do 300 damage to the first, and 50 to the second.

Comment: There are some abilities that do (case 1) +X damage per % Missing HP like Nidalee but there are (case 2) +X Damage per Y*HP missing like Garen. Example case 1 : 50% Life => 50X Dmg. Example Case 2: 6000HP * 50% = 3000 HP missing => 3000Y damage (For garen Y = 1/2.5 ) ==> + 1250 Dmg but if you have 1K HP it s + 200Dmg So As a Mundo you will fear more garen ultimate than nidalee takedown

Comment: You're right on that one, I think % missing HP needs to be tested unless I completely misunderstand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

For champions you have:

- **Dr. Mundo**'s cleaver deals % current hp as magic damage
- **Elise**'s toxin deals % current hp as magic damage
- **Elise**'s bite deals % missing hp as magic damage
- **Kog'Maw**'s spittle deals % max hp as magic damage
- **Varus**'s blight deals % max hp as magic damage
- **Vayne**'s silver bolts deal % maxp hp as true damage
- **Warwick**'s hungering strike deals % max hp as magic damage

And for items:

- **Blade of the Ruined King**'s passive deals % max hp as physical damage
- **Deathfire Grasp**' active deals % max hp as magic damage

Personally though, from a tank perspective, I'd be more terrified of true damage sources. That's what makes **Vayne** such a game changing hyper carry in the late game. **Ahri** and **Irelia** are also strong tank shredders thanks to their high true damage output.

Comment: As you pointed out, true damage is the dangerous part.

Comment: Missing at least Blackfire Torch and Liandry's Torment.

Comment: Missing a few more apparently, Domenick's answer is more complete.