# Which champions have non-ultimate skills that gains a bonus based on the target's missing health?

Tags: league-of-legends

Which non-ultimate champion abilities deal extra damage based on missing health? (such as Elise's spider form Q `Venomous Bite`)

Comment: not certain but think its a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107677/what-abilities-do-health-damage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fizz's Seastone Trident (W Passive) deals a flat amount plus 4 / 5 / 6 / 7 / 8% of target's missing health in magic damage over 3 seconds.
2. Kha'Zix's Evolved Enlarged Claws (Evolved Q) grants him bonus physical damage equal to 8% of target's missing health as bonus physical damage. This damage will be increased by 45% if the target is isolated. 11.6% of targets missing health if isolated.
3. Lee Sin's Resonating Strike (Second Q) deals flat physical damage plus 8% of the target's missing health.
4. Nidalee's Takedown (Second Q) deals 2% increased damage for every 1% of the target's missing health.
5. Volibear's Frenzy (W) deals 1% increased damage for every 1% of the target's missing health.

More info: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Health